# Does Firebase database triggers support preconditions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Does firebase database triggers support preconditions as in beforeCreate() or beforeDelete()?

If not, is there a method to achieve the same result without writing every thing to the database and then checking for validity of the data?

Comment: would  be interested to know the answer too. Although I feel like this would be sort of against their whole pricing philosophy.

Comment: Wouldn't it reduce their resource usage? :)

Comment: I don't think they are concerned about that ;) Every request to db is an excuse to charge you, why would they try to reduce that?

Comment: Have you considered [.validate conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#validate) in your security rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Cloud Functions run after the corresponding Firebase Database event has occurred. There is no support for running functions before the corresponding write operation to the database has occurred.

As Bob commented: one way to validate data before it is written to the database is with validation rules. While the format might be a bit unfamiliar at first, there are surprisingly complex scenarios you can implement in security rules. These rules are evaluated server-side before data is written to the database, and there is no separate charge for them.

Alternatively you can write the data to a "moderation queue" from the app. There you'd have Cloud Functions read it from, validate it, and then write to the final destination. While it isn't as clean as security rules, it may work better for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks. While reading the docs it seems I can use HTTP triggers and then write to DB. Thinking of using that method.

Comment: That would work indeed. It just means that your client-side code will need to handle reconnects and failures. If you use the database for intermediary too, you get the network resilience for free.